# Open Search Suggestion Fragment in full screen when the edit text is selected

Tags: android, fragment, fullscreen

I have a situation where the search box can be anywhere on the screen, once the user select the search box, i want show the Search Suggestion fragment on full screen, i populate the suggestion list as the user types in, on done i want to close the fragment and populate the selected text on the search box, similar to google PlaceAutocompleteFragment. what are the building blocks i need? thank you in advance, this is my first question sorry if there are any formatting issue in my question

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do it by designing transparent screen with EditText on screen. and start activity for results on Parent activity EditText onfocus